# java Pre-validation big number parameters in requests

Tags: java, rest, validation, servlets, jax-rs

I have in my resource class such method:

```
@GET
@Path("/")
public Result list(@BeanParam Pageable pageable) {
    ...
}
```

And the Pageable is:

```
public class Pageable {
@QueryParam("offset")
@DefaultValue("0")
private int offset;

...
```

When I pass big number in GET parameters, it fails with 404.
How can I pre-validate request value to return error that parameter is too big?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `@Max(Integer.MAX_VALUE)`?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work. I think, the request terminated before this validation.

Comment: Then it is a good question. I would like to know how to achieve this

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your development tool of your browser with the request. And read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string

Comment: I am not sure how big your number, but maybe you can use long instead of int.